# SWT update UI when closing application

Tags: java, user-interface, swt

I have an event listener in close action, inside the listener I need to show some messages in the UI text field. however it looks like the UI is not been updated even if syncExec is used instead, the Runnable does not update the UI.

```
    shell.addListener(SWT.Close, new Listener() {
        public void handleEvent(Event event) {

            display.asyncExec(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                if(!text.isDisposed()) {
                     text.setText("app closing");    
                  }
            });
    });  

   while(!shell.isDisposed()) {
        if(!display.readAndDispatch()) {
            display.sleep();
        }           
   }
```

Any idea?, I am new in SWT. 
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The `SWT.Close` event is sent just before the shell is actually disposed. By the time the code returns to the main `while(!shell.isDisposed())` loop the shell will be marked as disposed so the loop will terminate and the UI will not be updated again (it is the `display.readAndDispatch()` call that actually updates the UI).

You can sort of get this to work by calling `readAndDispatch` in the close listener although I really don't like this:

```
shell.addListener(SWT.Close, event -> {
   text.setText("app closing");

   Display display = shell.getDisplay();

   // Get events from setText dispatched
   while (display.readAndDispatch())
     { /* Do nothing */ }

   display.update();

   // TODO may need to sleep here
});
```

Testing this here the shell closes so quickly after this event that there was not time to see the update - I had to add a sleep at the end of the listener (which is even more ugly).